# Denying usage of applications in android

Tags: android, administrator, developer-tools

I am developing an **administrative application** that has functions like denying usage of camera, locking the user device or setting passwords.
Is it possible to also restrict the usage of  certain applications like facebook or youtube or dropbox? What are the permissions required? Can anyone help?

Comment: please explain more...didn't got your problem ?

Comment: Can I restrict the user from accessing installed applications on his phone through my administrator application? Like is it possible yo block applications?This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) helped me use apis that block camera and lock user screen. Is it also possible to block applications?

Comment: I didn't worked on this but i would suggest...you can get all the installed application along with their calling intent and package...and you could try to restrict if someone calling that intent.